# Book navigation pager is moved under the comments

Tags: theming, 8

For some reason, if I change the display order of any field in *Manage display* for the *Article* content type, the *Book navigation pager* is moved to the far bottom under the comments.

> [image]

If I check the template output, it is showing under the comments, which was not the case when everything was right. Even reordering the fields in *Manage display* to where they were before fixes this.

> [image]

Is there any reason for what happens? Is it a bug?

I am using the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme, if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a weight issue.

First: Try actually setting the field display weights.

1) Click the "Show row weights" button.
[image: Show Row weights link]

2) This will replace the drag and drop interface with an integer weight field. Set the weights to be lower (more negative) for all of your field items. Hopefully, this will allow them to float above the comments field.

Second: If the above doesn't work, then you might have to manually set the weight of the elements by altering the form.

You will need to place your code in a custom module. And then using [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x) alter the weight of the comments form.

Your code would look something like this:

```
// This part would go at the top of your mymodule.module file.    
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
```

This is where you actually set the  weight of the comment form.

```
function mymodule_node_view(&$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  // This probably isn't exactly what it will look like for you, but it's close-ish.
  if ($entity->getType() == 'book' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // Not exact, but this should be pretty close as well.
    $build['comments']['#weight'] = 30;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried both methods, but no luck. Your weight logic looks sensible but looks like this is not a issue. If you get any further idea please let me know. Thx for answer.

Comment: Could you check to see what the weights of the comment block and the navigation are?

Comment: It is indeed a weight issue. When I did check the weight for book-navigation in Book module in file book.module at line 238. It is 100. So need to put more more than 100 for comments. Now it is working. I was not expecting it will be this much for book navigation..

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: I have to wait 21 hrs to award you bounty as system is not allowing to do that because it is just 3 hr when I assigned bounty to this question. It has to be 24 hr.